# Checked radion button based on model variable + Spring forms + JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-form

I have model called `cuntry.java` with variable `lang` .I want to check the radio button option in JSP based on the `lang`. It could be 'EN' or 'FR'. when i wrote below code, throwing error in JSP page.

Code:

```
<form:radiobutton path="lang" id="language" value="FR" name="radios" <c:if ${cuntry.lang == 'FR' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' } /> ></form:radiobutton>
```

Error : `Unterminated &lt;form:radiobutton tag`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple errors in the form tag. When using Spring tags, you may not specify `id` and `name` attributes. They will be generated automatically from `path` variable. Tag `<c:if ... />` inside another tag `<form:radiobutton ... />` is not allowed. Remove end tag  as well. This is the right way

```
<form:radiobutton path="lang" value="FR" checked="${cuntry.lang == 'FR' ? 'checked' : '' }" />
```

If the value of `cuntry.lang` is `FR`, the Spring tag will result the following HTML (after compiling)

```
<input id="lang" name="lang" checked="checked" type="radio" value="FR" />
```

otherwise

```
<input id="lang" name="lang" type="radio" value="FR" />
```

If you absolutely need attributes `id = language` and `name = radios`, you can not use Spring tag .

You will find a good example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-radiobutton-and-radiobuttons-example/).

Answer (score 3):

`<c:if>` tag works on tags rather than attributes. As a result, your html syntax becomes invalid.

I haven't done jsp for quite a while. this should more or less work:

```
<form:radiobutton checked="${cuntry.lang == 'FR' ? 'checked':''}" path="lang" id="language" value="FR" name="radios">
</form:radiobutton>
```

If you insist on using `<c:if>` tag for this, you can do this:

```
<c:if test="${cuntry.lang == 'FR'}">
    <form:radiobutton checked="checked" path="lang" id="language" value="FR" name="radios">
    </form:radiobutton> 
</c:if>
<c:if test="${cuntry.lang != 'FR'}">
    <form:radiobutton path="lang" id="language" value="FR" name="radios">
    </form:radiobutton> 
</c:if>
```

You can also use `<c:choose>,<c:when>,<c:otherwise>` tags to solve this problem.

Obviously the first solution looks better.